# To Compare two space delimited files

Tags: shell, awk

I have two files as below .I want to compare and know whether the 2 rows are the same or not in both files.

file1.txt :

```
4162 8171.0 2.00 F NULL NULL 25.630 2010-05-05
256 45.2 5.00 N NULL NULL 16.098 2011-11-20
```

file2.txt :

```
4162 8171.0 2.00 F NULL NULL 25.630 2010-05-05
561 41.0 10.00 N NULL NULL 16.098 2011-11-20
```

I used below code using awk command.

```
rownum=1
cat file1.txt | while read -r LINE || [[ -N $line ]];
do 
row_same=`awk "/$LINE/ {print ;} " file2.txt;
if [[ "$row_same" = '' ]]
then 
    echo "row $rownum is Not matching "
else [[ "$row_same" != "$LINE" ]]
then
    echo "row $rownum is Not Matching "
fi
rownum=$((rownum+1))
done
```

Expected Output :

```
Row 2 is not Matching
```

Actual Output "

```
Row 1 is not Matching
Row 2 is not Matching.
```

Please help me why this is not working.

Comment: No I have not used diff, Please suggest me whihc is easy to implement.(even if files have special characters also in between)

Answer (score 0):

`diff` is a good one for doing this , however if you want to read line by line from both the files , you don't even need to use `awk`.

```
count=0
while IFS= read -r lineA && IFS= read -r lineB <&3
  do count=`expr $count + 1`
  if [ "$lineA" != "$lineB" ]; then
    echo "Line $count is not matching"
  fi
done <file1.txt 3<file2.txt
```

Comment: You should not use old and outdated back-tics, use parentheses like this:  `do count=$(expr $count + 1)`.  If you shell support it, use double bracket to speed it up. `if [[ "$lineA" != "$lineB" ]]; then`

Comment: And you can change the increment of `count` to just: `do ((count++))`

Answer (score 0):

Example using `diff`

```
diff -y file1.txt file2.txt
4162 8171.0 2.00 F NULL NULL 25.630 2010-05-05                  4162 8171.0 2.00 F NULL NULL 25.630 2010-05-05
256 45.2 5.00 N NULL NULL 16.098 2011-11-20                   | 561 41.0 10.00 N NULL NULL 16.098 2011-11-20
```

Here it shows that there is a difference in line #2, marked by the symbol `|`